# Meaning of “ at a height of “ in sentence

Tags: meaning

> It can be dangerous to load the truck at a height of four meters .

In this sentence what i confuses me is whether “ at a height of “ is used to describe the height of level where truck is loaded or the height of load.

Comment: The sentence is confusing. One loads things **to** a height of..., not **in** a height of. These heights are important both for stability and to avoid striking overhead bridges. But your sentence makes nothing clear, whether the total height above the road surface or above the truck's cargo bed.

Comment: My assumption on reading that sentence is that it was written by a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is badly written.  Literally it means "when the truck is 4 metres above  something (eg above the ground, or above sea level)

Pragmatically that doesn't make much sense. Pragmatics beat literal meaning. So I understand it to mean "to a height of 4 metres".  I know this *only* because I have some common knowledge about loads on trucks, and what is likely or not to be dangerous.

This kind of sentence reminds us that understanding isn't a simple process of looking at the words. We always use our knowledge of the world to interpret the words, especially when there are mistakes.